# EmacsLisp : Can the pixel width of text in a proportional font be measured?

Tags: faces, elisp

Given a face using a proportional font, can an accurate pixel width of a single row of text be measured in Emacs?

<sub>Note: not monospaced text.</sub>

Comment: Looks like `(- (car (pos-visible-in-window-p (line-end-position) nil t)) (car (pos-visible-in-window-p (line-beginning-position) nil t)))` should do that. The given example measures the width of the current line. The beginning and the end of line must be visible. The above version is not foolproof yet. See the documentation for `pos-visible-in-window-p`. Maybe, there is a better way.

Comment: My emacs-version is 24.3.1. The last section of the help for `pos-visible-in-window-p` states that the function returns the position in pixels if `PARTIALLY` is non-nil.

Comment: Unfortunately for my needs, I need to do this on text that isn't visible.  But this answers the question I posed, so please repost the original comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: I'd prefer to use your one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In the Emacs 24.4+ Manual Section 37.10 Size of Displayed Text](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-of-Displayed-Text.html)

> The following function returns the size in pixels of text as if it were displayed in a given window.
>
> **Function:** `window-text-pixel-size &optional window from to x-limit y-limit mode-and-header-line`
>
> This function returns the size of the text of window’s buffer in pixels. `window` must be a live window and defaults to the selected one. The return value is a cons of the maximum pixel-width of any text line and the maximum pixel-height of all text lines.
>
> The optional argument `from`, if non-nil, specifies the first text position to consider and defaults to the minimum accessible position of the buffer. If `from` is `t`, it uses the minimum accessible position that is not a newline character. The optional argument `to`, if non-nil, specifies the last text position to consider and defaults to the maximum accessible position of the buffer. If `to` is `t`, it uses the maximum accessible position that is not a newline character.

See the documentation for full details on the other parameters.

**Please Note:** window-text-pixel-size is a function introduced in emacs 24.4

Comment: Just a note: `window-text-pixel-size` is a function introduced in emacs 24.4. It does not yet exist in emacs 24.3.1 shipped with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: That's ok, I'm only interested in the current release of Emacs